# How to distinguish between dark matter and dark antimatter?

Tags: dark-matter, antimatter

I know dark matter exists to account for the missing mass otherwise many galaxies should have already fall apart, unfortunately they seldom interact with other matter and perhaps even their own kind except we know they're real to account for distortion of light of many galaxies...

**Would electron/positron and photon or maybe other known particles be produced as a result of collision between dark matter - dark matter or dark matter - dark antimatter?**

Comment: first you have to figure out what dark matter is and if in fact there is such a thing as dark matter.

Comment: Your first two questions are plausibly related enough to ask in one go; your third one is a topic unto itself and deserves its own question. I suggest editing it out and asking a new question for that one.

Comment: @KyleOman: done and I made the question much more clearer.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Magnetic_Spectrometer) and [its results from 2013/2014](http://www.livescience.com/47922-cosmic-rays-reveal-more-about-dark-matter.html).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, nobody knows the answer to those questions, because nobody knows for sure what is dark matter and if dark matter exists at all. According to supersymmetry, a theory beyond the Standard Model, there are much more particles than those which were discovered so far. And some of the particles this theory predicts could be potential candidates for being dark matter particles.
But like I said, until we know what is dark matter and whether it exists, no one can give an answer to your questions.

Comment: you're true, nobody knows. But, there is lot of models stating on anti dark matter and what happens in a collision and decay. Our collisions are strongly linked to EM ; for dark matter probably not.